# mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I want to run multiple mysql queries( not concurrently). I am using prepared statements for doing so. This is a gist of my code :

```
    <?php



if(isset($_GET['username'])&&isset($_GET['activationid'])){

require_once("../database/db_connect.php");

$stmt= $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare("Select username FROM users where username= ? AND activationid= ?");
$username=$_GET['username'];
$activationid=$_GET['activationid'];
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$username,$activationid);
$stmt->execute();
$row=$stmt->get_result()->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if(!strcmp($row['username'],$username)){
    echo 'you are registered successfully';



$stmt->prepare("UPDATE users SET active=yes where username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
$stmt->execute();







}
}

?>
```

and db_connect.php is :

```
<?php 





define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','root');
define('DBPASS','password');
define('DBNAME','Reminder');

    $mysqli= new mysqli(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DBNAME) ;
    if($mysqli->connect_error) { 

    echo $mysqli->mysqli_connect_error();

    }
else {
echo "connected successfully";
}




?>
```

This gives me this error :

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match
>   number of parameters in prepared statement in

can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: is that not a string `active='yes' `? and where you get $userid` ? isn't it `$stmt->bind_param("ss",$username,$activationid);`

Comment: i have set active column to be an enum

Comment: Am I missing something, or have you created two variables "$username" and "$userid". If so, $userid isn't defined.

Comment: sorry, i made a mistake. But i am still getting errors. I have made the edit, please see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please chenge your code like below and check:-

```
//$stmt= $mysqli->stmt_init(); comment this line
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("Select username FROM users where username= ? AND activationid= ?") or die( $mysqli->error);
$username=$_GET['username'];
$activationid=$_GET['activationid'];
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$userid,$activationid);
$stmt->execute();
```

And for second one same :-

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users SET active=yes where username = ?") or die($mysqli->error);
$stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
$stmt->execute();
```

Note:- Please take care that your variables are properly defined and set. thanks.

Comment: could you please add the code to run another statement after executing the first ?

Comment: do you mean can Harvey re-use a $stmt with a re-bind on say a 2nd call ?

Comment: if you don't check for errors after binding then you can chase your tail, especially on joins with ambiguity to innards but not ambiguous to the coder

Answer (score 1):

after you prepare and after you bind, (and before execute), do a

`echo $mysqli->error;`

nothing like knowing what the heck is going on

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It answers _every_ question.